# Installing flume agent on windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, avro, flume, flume-ng

I want to install flume agent on my windows10 for taking logs into my hortonworks sandbox installed on virtual box.
i did all setup refering this link-https://gudisevablog.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/apache-flume-windows-10/ but it occured some problem when i run this

command - " flume-ng agent –conf %FLUME_CONF% –conf-file %FLUME_CONF%/flume-conf.properties.template –name agent"

ERROR- Sourcing environment configuration script C:\flume\apache-flume-1.7.0-bin\conf\flume-env.ps1
WARN: Did not find C:\flume\apache-flume-1.7.0-bin\conf\flume-env.ps1
Including Hadoop libraries found in (C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.6.0) for DFS access
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
WARN: HBASE_HOME not found
WARN: HIVE_HOME not found

Running FLUME agent :
    class: org.apache.flume.node.Application
    arguments: -n agent -f "C:\flume\apache-flume-1.7.0-bin\conf\flume-conf.properties.template"

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\flume\apache-flume-1.7.0-bin\bin\flume-ng.ps1:189 char:10
+     $x = Start-Process $javaPath -ArgumentList "$fullJavaCommand" -Wa ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

i did all setting given on that blog can someone tell me where i'm stuck??

Comment: Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is a issue with your JAVA_HOME path. In order to debug the issue simply print the command on console using Write-Host command as shown below:

```
Write-Host "Start-Process $javaPath -ArgumentList '$fullJavaCommand' -Wait -NoNewWindow"
```